# Is there a better way to do jquery Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

Below is the jquery code I am using for my AJAX tabs

Is there a better way that would be faster in the browser, I don't care about fancy transitions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageUrl = new Array();          
pageUrl[1] = "HOMEbulletin.inc.php";
pageUrl[2] = "HOMEfriendstatus.inc.php";
pageUrl[3] = "HOMEbulletin.inc.php";

function loadTab(id){
    if (pageUrl[id].length > 0){
        $("#loading").show();
        $.ajax({url: pageUrl[id], cache: false, success: function(message) {                            
            $("#tabcontent").empty().append(message);
            $("#loading").hide();             
        }
    });                 
}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
        loadTab(1);
        $('div.tabs2 ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab2").click(function(){
        loadTab(2);
        $('div.tabs2 ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $("#tab3").click(function(){
        loadTab(3);
        $('div.tabs2 ul.HOMEtabs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it appears you solved it yourself, I'll offer an alternative as well.

You could have also added a call to the new click function of the tab you wanted to call at the end of your document.ready():

```
$("#tab1").click();
```

Comment: Thanks this is good to know about the click() function, also I changed the question since I solved it before anyone replied so it wouldn't be a wasted space on this site.  Another way I just tried to was this 
    $("#tab1").addClass('selected');
is it better to use the javascript or just hardcode class="selected" on page load in the html?

Comment: Update I just tried $("#tab1").click(); but it doesn't seem to do anything, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [JQueryUI's Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)? They're pretty excellent. No need to reinvent the wheel. It also adds support for some neat features like using a cookie to save whatever tab the user was on last.

If you're worried about filesize, you can grab only the components you need, alternatively:

[You can use Google's hosted copies of both JQuery and JQueryUI, it uses their entire network, and is extremely fast.](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/)

[3 Reasons to let Google host for you - Encosia.com](http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)